# Recovering Very Important Lost Data From Ntfs Partition

Tags: ntfs, data-loss, data-recovery

I have a 230 Gigs HDD on my laptop,
i have 50 gigs extended for my linux,
i have 80 gigs empty ntfs partition,
and 100 gigs ntfs partition where i store all my important data, (i have about 50 gigs of important things)
today i mounted the 100 gigs partition took something from it, unmounted it back,
and then when i mounted it again it was EMPTY !!!
all the data is gone !!!!
i used to mount it via the terminal : sudo mount ntfs /dev/sda5 /media/E
where E is a dir that i make (when i make it i change the permissions of media to 777 then after creating the dir, i change it back to normal)

Guys you cant imagine how much this data is important to me, Plz HelP, 
thnx in advance

Comment: ntfsck.  it was just an unclean unmount.  ntfs keeps two copies of the mft anyway.  alternately, on the windows side from recovery console chkdsk /F

Comment: http://www.sysresccd.org/Sysresccd-manual-en_Backup_data_from_an_unbootable_windows_computer

Comment: You need an expert advice because data are extremely valuable than anything. Hence, don't do anything else contact with a data recovery provider immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data is REALLY important. Stop using the disk/partition NOW. Unmount it! And do a read only copy of the disk. Every time you try to recover something on the original disk you are in danger of loosing more data. Then try recovery tools on the copied disk image. You can create an image with `dd if=your_partition of=your_disk_image_file bs=512` (hope the syntax is correct)

Comment: Have a look here as well https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery and here http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Tools:Data_Recovery

Answer (score 4):

Sometime ago I had a problem with the XP system disk that I was using. This was before I became a Ubuntu convert.
I removed the disk, installed another and started using Ubuntu.
Browsing through forums, I discovered TESTDISK, which is in the Ubuntu repositories.
Re-installed the corrupted disk, ran TESTDISK against it, rebuilt the partitions and recovered my XP system and all the data files.
In fact, I'm using that same faulty XP disk now for my Operating systems disk.

Comment: testdisk's home page. http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk It is in Ubuntu's repositories so it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install testdisk`