# Harddisk problem

Tags: 12.04, lts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All files erased after installing Ubuntu 11.04 alpha 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30791/all-files-erased-after-installing-ubuntu-11-04-alpha-3)
>   [Recovering Very Important Lost Data From Ntfs Partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124432/recovering-very-important-lost-data-from-ntfs-partition)

How to recover entire hard disk lost while installing the ubuntu, I chose the option `replace` ubuntu in windows 7 and formatted the entire disk.

And lost the all file how to recover all files in windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [TestDisk Utility](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) . Is a power tool that (sometimes) can recover entire partitions. You can install it in Ubuntu with this command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install testdisk
```

The other good utility is [foremost](http://foremost.sourceforge.net/)

Either way you should definitely read this => [Data Recovery - Ubuntu Community Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)