# How to recover files lost in Xubuntu installation?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, files, data-recovery

After installing Xubuntu 12.10, I lost all my files, but I only wanted to delete all Operative Systems, not *my* files.

How can I recover my files and folders? Is there a program I can use for this?

Comment: Did you install 12.10 over top a current installation? Did you reformat the hard drive during the installation process?

Comment: i dont now, i follow instructions

Comment: I don't think we can help you unless we know if you installed over top or reformatted the drive. It sounds like you reformatted your drive meaning it will be difficult to recover your data. This might help: http://www.linuxforu.com/2012/05/how-to-recover-deleted-files-linux-1/

Comment: i dont think i reformatted disk, now i have File System, and nothing more, i now that after installation on desktop should be 2 icons- for ex. Volume 70Gb

Comment: See - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: You might want to have a look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124432/recovering-very-important-lost-data-from-ntfs-partition/124453#124453

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery. Link has details to recover lost deleted files.

http://ubuntu-rescue-remix.org/About.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EJdx2ORi3r4. Data recovery using photorec.