# Data recovery - ext4

Tags: data-recovery, ext4, testdisk

I'm an idiot because I just "initialized" 2TB drive by mistake in Windows disk manager. So I lost all data. It had only one ext4 partition. I tried to run Testdisk but It didn't help me. Is it possible to somehow recover the data?

Comment: this may help you http://askubuntu.com/a/537143/260379

Answer (score 1):

You can try exundelete, downloadable from Sourceforge. Details of the use is here http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/

Hope it helps.