# I did mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0 without knowing it wipes the whole data

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, ext4

So guys I got panicked since my data gone, I tried the solution to use backup Superblock from this askubuntu [page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873348/recover-ext4-file-system-after-quick-format)  but still no luck. but when I tried sudo fsck.ext4 -vy /dev/md0 I got this message
/dev/md0/ clean, 11/244178944 files, blablablah.

[this is the screenshot I get from sudo fsck.ext4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teeZF.png)

Do I still have a chance to recover that 244000++ files?
the guy from the link said when suitable superblock has been found, I can recover the data, Did I use the wrong superblock?

*edit*
So I did the sudo blkid and what I get is
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25n7a.png)

dev/sda1, sdb, sdd1, and sdc is the Raid HDD that contains the whole file that I meant. So what can I do next?

Comment: `/dev/md0` is not mounted.  You will need to look at UUIDs.  I would recommend that you edit your question and add the following output.  `sudo blkid`.  There you will probably see something like `/dev/md0p1: UUID="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" BLOCK...`  The UUID is what can be added to your `/etc/fstab` file to mount the device of `/dev/md0` so that you should be able to hopefully browse your files again.

Comment: /dev/md0 not mounted is intentional tbh to make sure nothing is written to the HDD. But should I mount first before doing sudo blkid or I can do it without mounting the dev/md0?

Comment: `blkid` reads only the UUID regardless of if the drive is mounted or not.  But, without mounting the `/dev/md0` you cannot browse into it to see all your files.

Comment: okay so I already found the UUID, what can I do next? Do I have to edit the /dev/md0 UUID to the same UUID as the raid HDD?

Comment: You need to give it a mount point.  Make a directory like `sudo mkdir /media/storage` or something like that.  Then add a line to the bottom of your `/etc/fstab` file like `UUID=6e5c07a5-d751-490a-92a6-2d1dee2237e9 /media/storage   ext4    defaults 0 0`.  Then after it is added then you can mount it by typing in `sudo mount -a` which should mount it at `/media/storage`.  It is just odd though that all of your other drives that are mounted have partitions on them, but this RAID does not.

Comment: I still didn't find any file when I mount the HDD

Comment: Unfortunately, I am only guessing right now based on the info you have given.  On the linked answer you put in your question the person did state to test the superblock numbers until they matched and then recovered that SuperBlock.  I hope it didn't overwrite the backup SuperBlocks that were there.