# Ubuntu 18.04 new installation over erased 16.04 failure

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I had Windows 8 and Ubuntu 16.04 and after making a clean install for Ubuntu 18.04 on the 16.04 partition, I got the message: `grub-efi-amd64-signed' package failed to install into /target/.` at the end of the installation and nothing boots up now.

This is how GParted looks.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [16.04 new installation gives grub-efi-amd64-signed failed installation /target/ ubuntu 16.04 at the end](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789998/16-04-new-installation-gives-grub-efi-amd64-signed-failed-installation-target)

Comment: I didn't make any changes or customization to the installation and the HDD wasn't a new one.

Comment: Can you boot with a Live USB, run the application `gparted` and include a screen shot of what your HDD now looks like in gparted?

Comment: After using Google for some time, I found some one explaining the problem as: there was something missing in the installation ISO that was supposed to be downloaded during the installation process, but it didn't. Actually this option was gryed out during the installation and I couldn't set up the network connection as usual. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I added an image of gparted above.