# Does using a live USB session overwrite an erased HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, data-recovery, partitioning

I accidentally erased my HDD and explained how on [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035303/accidentally-erased-the-entire-ubuntu-hard-drive). Now on bootup it gives me this screen.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUsSg.jpg]

Can I use a live USB to open it safely without any further damage so that I can try to restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep the preselected option 'Try Ubuntu without installing' when booting up the Live USB, it will not touch your HDD.